# how to read and store variable from txt in c (unknown number of variables)

Tags: c

the project should read any configuration txt file in the right format. 
There is a different number of variable in each configuration file. The variables exist in the form of:
variable name = variable content or variable name=variable content 
e.g. Name = Bob
how to read and store these variables for future use?

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [ask], and [mcve].

Comment: Can you read a line? Can you split a line on "="? Can you ignore whitespace? Can you read until EOf? Can you define and use structs? Via pointers? Can you malloc for structs? We need to know that, in order to tailor an answer to your needs. Please demonstrate your level of understanding by providing the best code you have, which gets closest to what you want to achieve. If that is not much more than a HelloWorld, then you are basically asking for a tutorial, which is off-topic here.